# How to solve the six elements equations below?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, numerical-methods, systems-of-equations

How to get the exact or numerical solutions of the six elements equations below?
$$\begin{cases}
\frac{c_1}{1-x_1}+\frac{c_2}{1-x_2}+\frac{c_3}{1-x_3}=0\\
\frac{c_1}{1-x_4}+\frac{c_2}{1-x_5}+\frac{c_3}{1-x_6}=0\\
c_1\ln{\frac{x_1}{1-x_1}}+c_2\ln{\frac{x_2}{1-x_2}} +c_3\ln{\frac{x_3}{1-x_3}}=0\\
c_1\ln{\frac{x_4}{1-x_4}}+c_2\ln{\frac{x_5}{1-x_5}} +c_3\ln{\frac{x_6}{1-x_6}}=0\\
\frac{x_1(1-x_1)}{x_4(1-x_4)}=\frac{x_2(1-x_2)}{x_5(1-x_5)}=\frac{x_3(1-x_3)}{x_6(1-x_6)}
\end{cases}$$
where $ c_1,c_2,c_3 $ are constants, and $x_i\in(0,1), i=1,2,3,4,5,6$. Using $y_i=1-x_i$ instead of $x_i$ makes the equations a little more succinct
$$\begin{cases}
\frac{c_1}{y_1}+\frac{c_2}{y_2}+\frac{c_3}{y_3}=0\\
\frac{c_1}{y_4}+\frac{c_2}{y_5}+\frac{c_3}{y_6}=0\\
c_1\ln{\frac{1-y_1}{y_1}}+c_2\ln{\frac{1-y_2}{y_2}} +c_3\ln{\frac{1-y_3}{y_3}}=0\\
c_1\ln{\frac{1-y_4}{y_4}}+c_2\ln{\frac{1-y_5}{y_5}} +c_3\ln{\frac{1-y_6}{y_6}}=0\\
\frac{y_1(1-y_1)}{y_4(1-y_4)}=\frac{y_2(1-y_2)}{y_5(1-y_5)}=\frac{y_3(1-y_3)}{y_6(1-y_6)}
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Have you tried a Nelder-Mead simplex search using the sum of the squared errors as the cost function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit 3**: Since we now know that $x_1 = x_4$ and $x_2 = x_5$ and that $x_3$ and $x_6$ are superfluous, I believe that the correct solution to the above system is the set of $(x_1,x_2)$ pairs related by

$$
\beta = {{c_1} \over {1-x_1}} + {{c_2} \over {1-x_2}}
\\
x_3 = 1 + { {c_3} \over {\beta} }
\\
\Rightarrow 
c_1 \ln \left( { {x_1} \over {1-x_1} } \right) + c_2 \ln \left( { {x_2} \over {1-x_2} } \right)
= -c_3 \ln \left( {{-\beta} \over {c_3} } - 1 \right).
$$

Since $\ln$ is nonlinear, I don't think the above can be simplified meaningfully.

**Edit 2**: So I updated the cost function to only use $x_1$, $x_2$, $x_4$, and $x_5$ since both $x_3$ and $x_6$ can be expressed in terms of them. I still get a different solution that depends on the starting point (I choose the four starting points using a random number generator). However, the solution *always* has the relations that $x_1 = x_4$ and $x_2 = x_5$. This suggests to me that there are still two superfluous relations in the system and I'd guess that the the first two equations can be combined with the last two to remove another two variables so that problem reduces to finding $x_1$ and $x_2$. Until then, I'd say that the problem is currently poorly formulated.

**Edit 1**: So the below will only get you one particular solution. If I change the initial guess to `[0.7; 0.8; rand(1); 0.7; 0.8; rand(1)]`, I get a different solution each time.

**Original Answer**:

Depending on the values of $c_1$, $c_2$, $c_3$, I can get solutions using the following Nelder-Mead simplex search in Matlab. Note that there is one difference with the equations given above: I assumed that $\ln ( x_6 / (1-x_3) )$ was a typo and that it should be $\ln ( x_6 / (1-x_6) )$, as that fits the pattern of the other equations.

Here is the cost function I used with some arbitrary values chosen for the constants:

```
function f = costfun(x)

c1 = 100;
c2 = -54;
c3 = 0.354;

if( any( x >= 1 ) || any( x <= 0 ) )
  f = inf;
  return;
end

f1 = ( c1 / ( 1 - x(1) ) + c2 / ( 1 - x(2) ) + c3 / ( 1 - x(3) ) ).^2;
f2 = ( c1 / ( 1 - x(4) ) + c2 / ( 1 - x(5) ) + c3 / ( 1 - x(6) ) ).^2;

f3 = ( c1 * log( x(1) / ( 1 - x(1) ) ) + ...
  c2 * log( x(2) / ( 1 - x(2) ) ) + c3 * log( x(3) / ( 1 - x(3) ) ) ).^2;
f4 = ( c1 * log( x(4) / ( 1 - x(4) ) ) + ...
  c2 * log( x(5) / ( 1 - x(5) ) ) + c3 * log( x(6) / ( 1 - x(6) ) ) ).^2;

f5 = ( x(1)*(1-x(1)) / x(4)/(1-x(4)) - x(2)*(1-x(2)) / x(5)/(1-x(5)) ).^2;
f6 = ( x(1)*(1-x(1)) / x(4)/(1-x(4)) - x(3)*(1-x(3)) / x(6)/(1-x(6)) ).^2;
f7 = ( x(2)*(1-x(2)) / x(5)/(1-x(5)) - x(3)*(1-x(3)) / x(6)/(1-x(6)) ).^2;

f = f1 + f2 + f3 + f4 + f5 + f6 + f7;

return;
```

I then used the following to estimate the solution:

```
[x, costval, exitflag] = fminsearch( @costfun, 0.5 * ones(6,1) );
```

For the above values of $c_1$, $c_2$, and $c_3$, I got the following estimate for $\mathbf{x}$ with a total squared error of $3.3112 \cdot 10^{-6}$:

```
x =

    0.7176
    0.8477
    0.1655
    0.7176
    0.8477
    0.1656
```

The below plot shows the squared error for each iteration of the Nelder-Mead search:

[image: Squared error vs iteration]

Comment: Thank you for your method and finding my typo. But may be there is an instance that makes the cost function small, but there is not a solution near it. At least there should be an exact solution near each estimated solution.

Comment: I don't understand how a solution could not be near a value that makes the cost function small. Is it not true that only a solution will make the cost function small?

Comment: May be there is a "solution" makes the cost function less than $10^-6$ but there is not a exact solution near this estimated solution.

Comment: Besides I need to figure out all the solutions of the function.

Comment: I can get the squared error down to $~10^{-18}$ by changing the termination conditions. What are your requirements here? The question asks for exact _or_ numerical solutions to the system of equations.

Comment: Do you know what the relation is between different solutions?

Comment: Ok, It's my fault and it's meanless. But I think that a numerical solution should near a exact solution. No matter how small the error can be, there is still a small possibility that there is no exact solutions near it.

Comment: I don't know. Can you find the relation?

Comment: @YangzheLau I think you have two superfluous equations in your system, e.g., you can remove both $x_3$ and $x_6$ by solving the first two equations for them and then substituting into the others.

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing that out. And three constant is too more. I can use $c_1/c_3,c_2/c_3$ instead.

Comment: Can you find the boundary or minimum distance between different solutions? I think your method can figure the solutions out with several additional conditions.

Comment: @YangzheLau To be honest, I am not sure what you mean. If you have access to Matlab/Octave, you should be able to play around with the above and modify it to fit your exact needs though.

Comment: I need to figure out all the solutions of the system of functions. And you're right $x_1=x_4,x_2=x_5$.

Comment: @YangzheLau I think all you have left to do is express $x_3$ in terms of $x_1$ and $x_2$ and then you will have all of your solutions from some combination of the $\ln$ functions. I'm pretty sure it will look like $c_1 \ln (x_1/(1-x_1)) + c_2 \ln (x_2/(1-x_2)) = -c_3 \ln ((c_1/c_3)/(1-x_1) + (c_2/c_3)/(1-x_2) + 1)$.

Comment: @YangzheLau I added what I believe to be the equation that yields all solutions to the top of my answer.